# Solving arbitrary 2D recurrence relation on a grid

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I have a discrete "Laplace-type" equation of the form
$$\alpha_{i-1,j-1}+\alpha_{i-1,j+2}+\alpha_{i+2,j-1}+\alpha_{i+2,j+2}-(\alpha_{i,j}+\alpha_{i,j+1}+\alpha_{i+1,j}+\alpha_{i+1,j+1})=0,$$
i.e. the sum of the inner square equals the sum of four sites adjacent to the inner square's corners, and want to solve it on a grid given the values on the boundary. I know from the well-known discrete Laplace equation
$$\alpha_{i-1,j}+\alpha_{i+1,j}+\alpha_{i,j-1}+\alpha_{i,j+1}-4\alpha_{i,j}=0$$
how to solve it iteratively, we just solve the equation above for $\alpha_{i,j}$ and find:
$$\alpha_{i,j}=\frac{\alpha_{i-1,j}+\alpha_{i+1,j}+\alpha_{i,j-1}+\alpha_{i,j+1}}{4},$$
thus the center site is the average of the adjacent sites and we can find a solution by iterating over the grid and setting the value of the codomain grid point $(i,j)$ to $\frac{\alpha_{i-1,j}+\alpha_{i+1,j}+\alpha_{i,j-1}+\alpha_{i,j+1}}{4}$. If I try this approach on the original equation my solution rapidly grows to infinity. Does this mean the equation has no stable solution or the appraoch is flawed? If so, how can I deal with such types of recurrences?

I realize this equation is probably more programming than pure maths, but all I could find regarding these type of problems are discretizations of differential equations, which this is not.

Comment: Once there are boundary conditions, it becomes a linear system. Are there boundary conditions?

Comment: @Ian Yes, everything's zero except on point where it is one

Comment: Then it is a linear system; if it is too large there are specialized methods for solving such systems but if it is not that huge then it is just a linear system and you can solve it.

Comment: @Ian In principle one could solve it as a linear system, but I'm already satisfied with numerical solutions. What are the specialized methods you mentioned?

Comment: Multigrid and similar such methods are out there for this kind of local problem.

Comment: @Ian Hey, thanks! I will look into it

Comment: Yeah, I already worried that this system to have some inherent problems with stability as it doesn't derive from a "nice" differential equation

Comment: Yeah. This doesn't even correspond to a graph Laplacian when written this way.

Comment: without boundary conditions the functions $u_{ij} = e^{\sqrt{-1}\alpha i} e^{\sqrt{-1} \beta j}$ are eigenvalues of any linear difference operator with constant coefficients. FFT methods often can be applied for such problems. Also I believe the equation approximates the Laplace equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stencil may be visualized as

```
j+2 +           +
 
j+1     -   -    
          o
 j      -   -    
 
j-1 +           +
   i-1  i  i+1 i+2
```

Let $h = \Delta x = \Delta y$. Let's analyze the Taylor expansion around $(x_{i+1/2}, y_{j+1/2})$ of the following expression
$$
\delta_{i+1/2,j+1/2} = \frac{u_{i-1,j-1} + u_{i+2,j-1} + u_{i-1,j+2} + u_{i+2,j+2}}{h^2} - \frac{u_{i,j} + u_{i+1,j} + u_{i,j+1} + u_{i+1,j+1}}{h^2}.
$$
Each term has the form
$$
R(u, z) = \sum_{m=+1,-1} \sum_{n=+1,-1} \frac{u(x_{i+1/2} + m z h, y_{j+1/2} + n z h)}{h^2}.
$$
So $\delta_{i+1/2,j+1/2} = R(u, 3/2) - R(u, 1/2)$.

Let $r, s$ be the coordinates in the rotated coordinate system with basis vectors $e_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 1)$ and $e_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, -1)$.

In the rotated system $R(u, z)$ can be written as
$$
R(u, z) = \sum_{m=+1,-1} \frac{u(r_{i+1/2,j+1/2} + \sqrt{2} m z h, s_{i+1/2,j+1/2})}{h^2} + 
\sum_{n=+1,-1} \frac{u(r_{i+1/2,j+1/2}, s_{i+1/2,j+1/2} + \sqrt{2} n z h)}{h^2}
$$
Now Taylor expansion of $R(u,z)$ is pretty straightforward:
$$
R(u,z) = \frac{4}{h^2} u_{i+1/2,j+1/2} + 2z^2 (u_{rr} + u_{ss})_{i+1/2,j+1/2}
+ O(h^2).
$$
Note that $u_{rr} + u_{ss} = u_{xx} + u_{yy} = \Delta u$.
Now we can finally get the expression for $\delta_{i+1/2,j+1/2}$:
$$
\delta_{i+1/2,j+1/2} = \frac{9}{2} (\Delta u)_{i+1/2,j+1/2} - \frac{1}{2} (\Delta u)_{i+1/2,j+1/2} + O(h^2) = 4 (\Delta u)_{i+1/2,j+1/2} + O(h^2).
$$
Indeed, your difference equation approximates $\Delta u = 0$ with second order.

As a numerical method I suggest using some direct solver for sparse matrices (works great for problems below $1000 \times 1000$, i.e. number of unknowns below $10^6$) or some iterative solver (if your problem is even bigger, but there is a quest of choosing a good preconditioner)